# Multiple rangesliders to sort a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a solution which sorts a table on multiple search criteria. I've been trying to get it to work but so far i didnt get it to work. Since it got a mess i decided to go back to a working script which is with only one slider. How can i get this to work?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o1ud4zj7/38/)

This is the script with one slider:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range, #slider-range2" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 20, 450 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        // in this function we can define what happens when a user changes the sliders
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );

        var table = document.getElementById("theTable");
        for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
           for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {

               if (j == 0) {        
                   if ($(col).html() >= ui.values[ 0 ] && $(col).html() <= ui.values[ 1 ]) {
                       $(row).show();
                   } else {
                       $(row).hide();
                   }
               }
           }  
        }          
      }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
});
```

Comment: Why not return your data from a DB sorted? you can try Jquery.Datatable with ajax calls to a stored procedure who filter with one or many parameters and return you data sorted?

Comment: because there is no DB(yet). Its all static